# TFS branching strategy with teamcity builds and octopus deploys

Tags: tfs, teamcity, octopus-deploy, teamcity-9.0

We have  TFS environment based branches. We have dev main release and hotfix.

Our octopus life cycle mandates that the code first be deployed into dev environment then into test env then into staging and then into production.

We develop in dev tfs branch and we have a Teamcity build that targets Dev branch and then triggers octopus deploy to deploy into Dev environment. But once dev testing is complete, we need to merge the code to Main branch and its from Main branch that we deploy it to test environment and then to staging and then to production.

How do i define the build and deployment in this case?

Comment: It seems your issue in less related to TFS. On TFS side, you just need to source control your branches, and perform merge between branches. You may need to create two Build Configurations to specify two TFS branches (dev and main) in Root of TeamCity to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your branching strategy will mean that some builds will only go to one environment:

1. Code new feature in Dev
2. Build Dev branch (artifact #1)
3. Deploy #1 to Dev environment
4. Merge to Main
5. Build Main branch (artifact #2)
6. Deploy #2 to Test environment
7. Deploy #2 to Staging environment
8. Deploy #2 to Production environment
9. Branch/Merge to Release branch for support

So in Octopus you'll need to have a Channel for Dev which will only be allowed to go to Dev environment and the default Channel will go from Test->Staging->Production. To support the channels you'll have to distinguish the version numbers away from each other or use SemVer extensions to help.